# how to write the scipy.optimize.minimize()'s parameter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using scipy.optimize.minimize() to get the minimum value and it's x,y

```
    def fun(self):
    cols=self.maintablewidget.columnCount()-1
    for k in range(3,cols):
        for i in range(1,k):
            d=string.atof(self.maintablewidget.item(i-1,k-1).text())
            xi=string.atof(self.xytablewidget.item(i-1,0).text())
            yi=string.atof(self.xytablewidget.item(i-1,1).text())
            f=lambda x,y: np.sum((np.sqrt((x-xi)**2+(y-yi)**2)-d)**2)

        res=optimize.minimize(f,0,0)#I do not know how to give the optimize.minimize's parameter
        print(res['x'][0])
        print(res['x'],res['fun'])
```

I do not know how to give the `optimize.minimize`'s parameter. Can someone explain to me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Essentially if your function depends on two parameters, you need to pass them as `x[0]` and `x[1]` instead of `x` and `y`. So in the end you function will depend on a single vector parameter `x`.For example:

```
f = lambda x: np.sum((np.sqrt((x[0]-xi)**2+(x[1]-yi)**2)-d)**2)
res = optimize.minimize(f, (initial_x, initial_y))
```

The minimum will be in `res.x` and will have the form of a vector `[x, y]`.

Comment: TypeError: minimize() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)  here is an error

Comment: It is complaining because you only gave `f`. You also have to input the initial value.

Comment: I Write like this. res=optimize.minimize(f,(0,0)),but there is still a problem. TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: did you rewrite your function `f` so that it takes only 1 argument `x`? It should look like this: `f=lambda x: np.sum((np.sqrt((x[0]-xi)**2+(x[1]-yi)**2)-d)**2)`

Comment: f=lambda x,y: np.sum((np.sqrt((x-xi)**2+(y-yi)**2)-d)**2)   I am new to scipy.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am going to try it！