# passing a function with multiple independent variables and multiple arguments to scipy optimize minimize

Tags: python, scipy, keyword-argument, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60386406/4999991), I want to make my question as specific as possible focusing on the part that I can not solve. Consider a very simple function of:

```py
def foo(x, y, a, b, c):
    return a * x**4 + b * y**2 + c
```

now I want to use the `scipy.optimize.minimize` or any of other existing functions to find the `x` and `y` (i.e., parameters) to minimize `foo` given the constants `a`, `b`, and `c` (i.e., args). If I had only one parameter and multiples arguments then from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017924/4999991) I could do:

```py
def foo(x, *args):
    a, b, c = args
    return a * x**4 + b * x**2 + c

# X0 = to some scalar
# ARGS = a tuple of scalars (A, B, C) 

x_min = scipy.optimize.minimize(foo, x0=X0, args=ARGS)
```

and if I had only independent variables, with no constant args, then from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670414/4999991) I could do:

```py
def foo(*params):
    x, y = params
    return 4 * x**4 + 2 * y**2 + 1

# P0 = to a list of scalars [X0, Y0] 

x_min = scipy.optimize.minimize(foo, x0=P0)
```

However, I can not use any of the above syntaxes. I believe I have to define my function as something like:

```py
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    x, y = args
    a, b, c = tuple(kwargs.values())
    return a * x**4 + b * y**2 + c
```

but then I don't know how to pass `args` and `kwargs` to the `scipy.optimize` functions. I would appreciate if you could help me understand what is the best way to define the `foo` function with multiple independent parameters and constant arguments to `scipy.optimize` functions. Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing `foo` and making scipy pass the constant arguments, you can bind them yourself, either using `lambda` or `functools.partial`:

```
A, B, C = some_const_values
foo1 = lambda x, y: foo(x, y, A, B, C)
```

Or:

```
import functools
foo1 = functools.partial(foo, a=A, b=B, c=C)
```

Then:

```
x_min = scipy.optimize.minimize(foo1, ...)
```

Comment: aha, cool workarounds. thank you. so there is no way to pass a function with `*args, **kwargs` directly to the `scipy.optimize` functions without defining a lambda or intermediary function?

Comment: I will test this in a couple o fhours and will come back to approve the answer.

Comment: I tried your code. I'm not sure if it will work as it is. I this the `x, y` parameters need to be smashed into one like `foo_ = lambda P: foo(P[0], P[1], A, B, C)` and then `minimize(foo_, x0=[X0, Y0])`. I'm not gonna apply this edit on your post you will not get any notifications. better you look at it your self.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682638/4999991) as an example

Answer (score 0):

We want to define a function foo that takes multiple independent variables (x and y) and also has constant arguments (a, b, and c), and then use the scipy.optimize.minimize function to find the values of x and y that minimize the function while keeping the constants fixed.

```py
import scipy.optimize

def foo(params, *args):
    x, y = params
    a, b, c = args
    return a * x**4 + b * y**2 + c

x0 = [1, 2]  # initial guess
args = (1, 2, 3)  # constant arguments a, b, c
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(foo, x0, args=args)

x_min = result.x[0]
y_min = result.x[1]

print("Optimized x:", x_min)
print("Optimized y:", y_min)
print("Minimum value of foo:", result.fun)
```

the foo function takes params as the list of independent variables x and y, and also takes the constant arguments a, b, and c as separate tuple of parameters using the *args syntax. We then pass the initial guess x0 for x and y, and the constant arguments a, b, and c using the args parameter of the scipy.optimize.minimize function.